# Why Xcode allows create duplicate Objective-C Category?

Tags: objective-c, categories

Xcode does not allow you to create duplicate class file. I'm curious why it allows you to create duplicate category file in different folders.

eg:
A folder
--- NSObject+Test
B folder
--- NSObject+Test

The project can run normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode and Objective-C do allow you to create duplicate class files. What it doesn't allow you to do is create duplicate *classes*. In Objective-C, it is traditional to name the file with the same name as the class, but this is neither universal, nor enforced.

The question I think you're asking is why does Objective-C allow multiple categories with the same name (regardless of what file they're in). The reason is because Objective-C doesn't really care very much what the name of a category is. Originally categories were a way to organize large classes into multiple files (which is why they're called "categories" rather than "extensions"). Eventually they came to be used to add new methods to existing classes. At no point along the way has the compiler really bothered very much with the category names (the part in parentheses). They're generally treated as a comment.

I wouldn't assume there was a specific moment when the language designers decided "it should be legal to have multiple categories with the same name." There's just never been checked for or prevented.

The more interesting and important collision is that two categories can add the same *method* name. This isn't prevented by the compiler but is actually a serious problem. It's not defined which method will execute and the compiler won't tell you you've made this mistake. This is why it's important to prefix category method names to prevent collisions. It's a good idea to prefix category names, too, for consistency.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation made me very cheerful.

Answer (score 0):

Why should the compiler care about the *file* name? Never heard that a compiler does such a thing.

And there might be reasons, i. e. if in Folder A resp. Folder B are different versions or configurations of the software.